# Web API Helper Class for Unit Testing POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the following extension method (which I confess I borrowed!) to help set a request when unit testing a POST to a Web API (v1) controller.

```
    public static void SetRequest(this ApiController controller, string controllerPrefix,
                          HttpMethod method, string requestUri)
    {
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        var route = controller.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var routeValues = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
        routeValues.Add("controller", controllerPrefix);
        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, routeValues);

        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);
        controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
                                                                   controller.Configuration);
        controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey, routeData);
    }
```

This works fine with a single route like the default one I already have, but the end solution will have multiple routes.

I don't want to create a separate helper for each route so I'd like to change this to handle multiple routes, but I'm struggling, apart from putting a switch statement around the  `var route` variable, but doesn't feel very elegant.

I thought about passing a collection of routes when setting the `var routeData`, but this doesn't seem possible.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you have to stick with Web API v1 or can u update?

Comment: Sadly, it needs to be Web API v1.

Comment: Why do you have to test the API through its route? I found this two links, but it looks like you have to add multiple routes. http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/16/unit-testing-asp-dot-net-web-api/  http://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/